# Как написать SQL триггер, который будет фиксировать изменения таблицы и вносить в новую

Tags: sql, триггер

Нужно чтобы триггер на таблицу при update столбцов добавлял данные в новую таблицу : Если командой update в таблице изменен 1 столбец, то триггер в новую таблицу вносит значение "1 1", Если командой update было изменено 2 столбца, то триггер в новую таблицу, которую он сам по идее должен и создать, добавляет значение "1 2".

Comment: 1) SQL-текст триггера сильно зависит от используемой СУБД - укажите её, включая версию. 2) В большинстве СУБД использование DDL в триггерах запрещено.

Comment: Таблицу новую можно вручную создать, главное чтобы триггер добавлял значения в ту таблицу. Версия СУБД mysql 8.0 или там 1.1.8. Еще если возможно то нужно чтобы триггер на пустой update тоже реагировал если допустим применить запись update xxx set x = x where false. То есть пустой update и вносил в таблицу значение 1 0. Соответственно если одно значение то 1 1, если два то 1 2. Больше не нужно.

Comment: *если допустим применить запись update xxx set x = x where false. То есть пустой update и вносил в таблицу значение 1 0.* Невозможно.

Comment: В любом случае - какая у Вас КОНКРЕТНАЯ проблема возникла при создании триггера? За Вас его кто-то писать уж точно не станет.